# Iterative Stored Procedure in a SQL Insert statemen

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I'm looking to do something to this effect.

Where I get a list of level 1 locations, insert a 'Main Office' level 2 location for each, and use my `Get_Next_PK` stored procedure iteratively in the insert statement.

I feel like I'm probably missing a glaringly obvious way to do this differently.

Level2 PK is not unique, and thus is also not an autoincrement/identity

```
DECLARE @foo INT

INSERT INTO LocationLvl2_Table
    EXEC Get_Next_PK 'LocationLvl2_Table', @foo OUTPUT

SELECT 
    @foo, LocationLvl1_Code, 'Main Office', 1
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT 
        LocationLvl1_Code
    FROM 
        LocationLvl1_Table
    WHERE...)
```

The result I'm getting: my function pulls the correct next PK, but only once, so all rows have the same PK. On top of that I'm seeing the data that I want to be inserted displayed in my results window, but none of the data actually gets inserted into the table

Sample Info:
I have 5 Lvl_1 locations, and 12 Lvl_2 locations (PK's 1-12). All 5 lvl_1's have 'main entrance' and 'cafeteria' lvl_2 locations. 2 of them have a 'main office' lvl_2.

I want to insert a 'main office' lvl_2 for each lvl_1 that doesn't have one.
(That logic starts where I trailed off on the where statement.)

`Get_Next_PK` would take 'location_lvl2' table name as a parameter, and return '13' as the next PK.

I want to iterate through each of the lvl_1's that don't have 'main office' and give them a lvl_2 using the SP's output variable (@foo) inside the insert statement.

Comment: Your `Get_Next_PK ` doesn't look like a function, it is a stored procedure. If you want to execute is for each row, you'll need a `cursor` or a `while loop`. But before that, can you share the code of `Get_Next_PK`? There must be a simpler way of doing it.

Comment: " Level2 PK is not unique" - if PK stands for Primary Key, and it ain't unique, you've got other problems.  :)

Comment: Correct about the stored procedure, not a function, that was my mistyping. I can't really share the code, unfortunately. And yes I know that the PK should be unique, but it's not, and I have to work around that.

Comment: If you can't share the code in the SP, how exactly do you expect us to help you? *I won't show you my code, but it ain't workin'. Can ya fix it fer me?*

Comment: Normally your level 2 key would refer (foreign key) to another table which is the 'master list' of level 2 locations which _does_ have a primary key you can use. To put it another way, normally you have another table which stores a unique list of level 2 locations and you use an identity in that to generate incrementing keys

Comment: @KenWhite Because the workings of my SP are not the thing in question here. I'm merely asking if it's possible to call the SP in an iterative manner for each new line of insertion.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm not sure I follow. The 'Main Office' of each lvl 1 location are unique level 2 locations. Having a third table to store 'Main Office' is impractical because we just don't have that many different types of lvl 2s.

Comment: The working of the SP are the *thing in the question here*, because the answer is *No, you can't do that, but if we knew what your SP was doing we might be able to suggest an alternate approach that would work instead.* If you don't want help, that's your prerogative. Just don't expect much of it when you refuse to provide information.

Comment: No one has outright said "No" to my question until now. The inner workings of the SP are not mine to share, which is why I'm not doing it. Essentially, if the highest PK in lvl2_table is 10, the SP OUTPUT is 11.

Comment: Perhaps provide some sample data - You mention level 2 PK but this does not appear anywhere in your example code so it's all a bit confusing.

Comment: No time to write a full answer right now, but suggest you use your proc to return the starting id number and then use the rownumber feature to increment the starting number by 1 for each row. You will need make sure you handle race conditions as there si a reason why autonumberimng is preferred to roll=-your-own ids.

Answer (score 0):

After some more googling, and a nudge in the right direction from @HLGEM I was able to make this work. Not ideal, I know, but it solved my problem.

```
DECLARE @foo INT
EXEC Get_Next_PK 'LocationLvl2_Table', @foo OUTPUT
INSERT INTO LocationLvl2_Table
SELECT @foo + ROW_NUMBER() over(order by LocationLvl1_Code), LocationLvl1_Code, 'Main Office', 1
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT 
    LocationLvl1_Code
FROM 
    LocationLvl1_Table
WHERE...)
```